# Como ajustar corretamente a altura da imagem em uma UITabBarItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, imagem, uitabbar

Configurei duas imagens para um `tabBarItem`. Como não encontrei um modo de alterar o centro da imagem, utilizei o seguinte método para fazer o efeito da imagem subir alguns pixels, acima da `UITabBar`:

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 0, -5, 0);
```

Funcionou perfeitamente!

Porém durante o uso, quando o botão é clicado várias vezes seguidas, a imagem é esticada.

Estado normal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Após alguns cliques seguidos sobre o botão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como ajustar corretamente a altura da imagem, ou alterar a altura da própria `UITabBarItem`, sem ocorrer este problema?

Answer (score 0):

Fiz alguns testes e notei que foi um problema de configuração.

O valor correto que deve ser enviado ao método devem ser iguais:

ERRADO:

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(4, 0, -5, 0);
```

CERTO

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, -5, 0);
```

Portanto este método serve ao propósito de ajustar a imagem no tabBarItem.